# Joining 2 tables based on a relation defined in a third table and putting several rows from the second table in a single row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm learning SQL and currently I'm trying to write an application using SQLite. Currently I have 3 tables:

cooperative:
  cid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  ...

person:
  pid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name STRING,
  ...

person_works_in_cooperative:
  cid INTEGER,
  pid INTEGER,
  job INTEGER

I want to produce a new table where each row have data from a cooperative and also have the pid from the person whose job is "0" (the president), "1" (the secretary), "2" (the treasurer) and the three people whose job is "4" (counselors).

Currently I'm being able to join the tables, but I couldn't find a way to merge 6 different rows of persons in the final table. Someone could please give me an advice of how to proceed?

EDIT: What I wrote so far is a long JOIN:

```
SELECT cooperative.cid, person.name AS president,  person.pid  AS president_pid,
person.name AS secretary,  person.pid  AS secretary_pid, person.name AS treasurer,
person.pid  AS treasurer_pid,  person.name AS counselor1, person.pid  AS 
counselor1_pid, person.name AS counselor2, person.pid  AS counselor2_pid, person.name
AS counselor3, person.pid  AS counselor3_pid FROM cooperativ1 LEFT JOIN 
person_works_in_cooperative ON cooperative.cid = person_works_in_cooperative.cid 
LEFT JOIN person ON person_works_in_cooperative.pid = person.pid;
```

But I'm not figuring how to tell the database that I want that each pair of person names and pids that I'm asking should correspond to different persons from the person table.

Comment: Show the SQL you wrote so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you all the columns from the three tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM cooperative c
    JOIN person_works_in_cooperative pw ON pw.cid = c.id
    JOIN  PERSON p ON pw.pid = p.id
WHERE pw.job IN (0, 1, 2, 4);
```

and will show you all the *presidents*, *secretaries*, etc for each *cooperative*.

If you want just the info from a specific *cooperative*, you can add an additional condition to the `WHERE` clause:

```
AND c.id = 1;
```

---

**EDIT**

If you, instead, want to have all the related informations on the same *row* as the one of the *cooperative*, that can't be done with plain SQL.

Comment: Thanks, but this query give me a different row for each person with a valid job in the database. But what I'm needing is that everyone who works in the same cooperative appears in the same row corresponding to that cooperative.

Comment: Like, if there are 3 people in cooperative 1, you want 3 columns for the row of that cooperative? And if 5 people work in cooperative 2, you want 5 columns for the row of that cooperative? If that's the case, I don't think this can be done with plain SQL, you should generate the query dinamically. If you have a RDBMS like Oracle you can compose your query dynamically, otherwise you have to rely to your server side programming language.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that isn't possible to do what I was planning with just one query. As you pointed, this would imply a way to get a table with a variable number of columns, and this wouldn't fit well into the relational model. Thanks for the answers. As the correct answer is "it cannot be done", I'll mark your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @ThiagoHarry Good. I edited the question to add that additional information :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.cid, 
       (select pid from person_works_in_cooperative pc0 where pc0.cid = c.cid and pc0.job = 0 ) "president",
       (select pid from person_works_in_cooperative pc1 where pc1.cid = c.cid and pc1.job = 1) "secretary",
       (select pid from person_works_in_cooperative pc2 where pc2.cid = c.cid and pc2.job = 2) "treasurer"
from cooperative c
```

This is only a solution for the president, secretary and treasurer per cooperative. Can't invent an easy solution for the 3 counselors. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry, I think I oversimplified the problem in my first post. I need to get not only the person's pid, but also the person's name, so I really need to join the 3 tables. Your solution really work for the president, secretary and treasurer after the join, but I'm worried about having to use a subquery to get each attribute for each person in each cooperative. Perhaps the best to do is write one more query to get all the people in PHP for each cooperative and combine the queries in the server side programming before printing the result.